# Dynamic sort options for SilverShop Module

Tags: php, silverstripe, silvershop

I have been breaking my head on how to do a dynamic sort option, which will show/hide the sort option, depending on whether the category has the "Manufacturer" that the sorter is looking for...

```
private static $sort_options = array(
    'Alphabetical' => 'URLSegment',
    'Lowest Price' => 'BasePrice'
);
```

Normally the sorter gets its options like this, but this will not seem to cut it for the task at hand.

If anyone can give some tips or ideas of what I can try, that would be really helpful. What am I missing?

Comment: Just to be clear about my problem
Product Category has Many Products
Products has Many Categories
Product has one Manufacturer
Manufacturer has many Products
What I need to do is have a sorter that shows the Manufacturers that the products in that Category has
and hide the Manufacturers that do not have Products in the Category

Comment: Commenting on the obvious atleast: it should be private static $sort_options   not public. Imho you should be getting a warning or an exception relating that.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to override the getSorter method in ProductCategory_Controller and add any additional logic there:

https://github.com/silvershop/silvershop-core/blob/master/code/product/ProductCategory.php#L202